# Solve the equation: $\lfloor{x}\rfloor+\lfloor{2x}\rfloor=\frac{5x-1}{2}$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Solve the equation:

$$\lfloor{x}\rfloor+\lfloor{2x}\rfloor=\frac{5x-1}{2}$$

Unfortunately I don't know how to approach this problem. I tried all the properties and I even tried Hermite's identity, but no luck.

Comment: In my opinion, the chief obstacle to successfully attacking such a problem is the Math Student's sense of identity, which emotionally resists the idea of dispensing with any attempt at elegance.  Generally, for problems of this nature, set $$x = P_x + r_x ~: ~P_x \in \Bbb{Z}, ~0 \leq r_x < 1.$$  This usually makes the problem **game over**.

Comment: Let $\lfloor x\rfloor = u$, $\lfloor 2x \rfloor = v$. Then $u+v=\frac{5x-1}{2}$, $u\leq x < u+1$, $v \leq 2x < v+1$. Solve this equation and two inequalities simultaneously, taking into account that $u$ and $v$ are integers.

Comment: Similar: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1755691p11461943

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The LHS is an integer, so the RHS must be one as well.  See if you can use this facts to get rid of the floor function and replace it with a linear polynomial of $x$

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to note is that $[x] + [2x]$ is an integer.

So $\frac {5x -1}2$ is an integer.

Let $\frac {5x -1}2 = W\in \mathbb Z$ then

$x =\frac {2W+1}5$ so $x$ is a fraction of an odd number numerator over denominator $5$.

So let $x = n + \frac k5$ where $n,k  \in \mathbb Z$ and $0 \le k < 5$.  (In other words where $2W+1 = 5n+k$)

Then $[x] = n$ and $2x = 2n + \frac {2k}5$ and $[2x] = 2n$ if $\frac {2k}5 < 1$ or $[2x] =2n + 1$ of $1 \le \frac {2k}5 < 2$

So

Case 1:  $\frac {2k}5 < 1$ or $2k < 5$ or $k =0,1,2$.

Then $[x] + [2x] = n + 2n = 3n$ and $\frac {5(n+\frac k5)-1}2 = \frac {5n+k-1}2=3n$

$5n +k -1 = 6n$

$n = k-1$ so $n=-1;k=0;x=-1$ or $n=0;k=1;x=\frac 15$ or $n=1;k=2;x=1+\frac 25$.

Case 2: $1\le \frac {2k}5 < 2$ or $5\le 2k < 10$ or $k=3,4$.

Then $[x] +[2x] = n +2n+1 = 3n+1$ and $\frac {5(n+\frac k5)-1}2=\frac {5n+k-1}2 = 3n+1$

$5n+k-1 = 6n +2$

$n = k-3$

And so $n=0;k=3;x=\frac 35$ or $n=1;k=4; x=\frac 95$.

Answer (score -1):

Method I:
Use inequality $x-1 < [x] \leq x$

$[x]+[2x] \leq x+2x = 3x \Rightarrow \frac{5x-1}{2} \leq 3x \Rightarrow -1 \leq x$

$x-1+2x-1 < [x]+[2x] \Rightarrow  3x-2 <\frac{5x-1}{2} \Rightarrow 6x-4 <5x-1  \Rightarrow x<3$

you can find a range for x: $-1 \leq x < 3$

Then you can divide it into 8 ranges in worst cases and solve them one by one. e.g. $-1 \leq x<-0.5, -0.5 \leq x <0$, etc (Deal to the term $[2x]$, I divide the ranges into steps of $0.5$)

We have $\frac{5x-1}{2}=-3,-2,0,?,?,?,?,?$ for those 8 ranges.

Then the corresponding solutions are $?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?$

Check with their ranges. Some of them are rejected, $?,?,?,?,?$ remained. They are the solutions. I keep some number as ? to let you try.

Method II: Use @user2661923 's method. You do not even need inequality.

Case I: Let $x = P+r , 0 \leq r <0.5$, P is integer.

$P+2P = \frac{5(P+r)-1}{2} \Rightarrow P=5r-1$

Put in $r=0,0.2,0.4$ give you 3 solutions.

Case II: Let $x = P+r , 0.5 \leq r <1$, P is integer.

$P+2P+1 = \frac{5(P+r)-1}{2} \Rightarrow P=5r-3$

Put in $r=0.6,0.8$ give you 2 solutions.

Comment: Would you mind explaining where I can get this ranges from?

Comment: Thank you! I am trying to solve it right now and your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if I am wrong but I checked the range and it gave me $-1\leq x\lt 1$

Comment: $1.8$ is a solution, so $x<1$ is wrong. I typed all steps for the inequality, you can compare your steps with mine.

Comment: @user2661923 's x=P+r trick is good and fast.